# How to create a popup on form submit

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form that comes from a third party (mailchimp/mailerlite). The problem I am having is that when I click on the button, it opens the form in a new window. I want it to popup instead of opening a new window. Can anyone give me some pointers?

**FORM**

```
<form ngNoForm id="someid" action="//app.mailerlite.com/webforms/popup/123123" target="_blank">
<div class="button-preview">
<button type="submit" class="ml-subscribe-button gradient-on">SIGN ME UP TODAY</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Aside from some CSS I also include a js script in my index file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.mailerlite.com/js/w/button.js?v20"></script>
```

Below is a working example of what I am trying to accomplish. Note that the website below is created using plain HTML5 but I am trying to switch to Angular2.

**Click on the SIGN ME UP TODAY button:**
http://www.hedaro.com

Comment: why not to use bootstrap-modal for the same using `data-toggle='modal'`?

Comment: If I was creating my own form then yes I would try a modal. The problem is that the code I provided comes from a third party and I am just trying to tweak it to get my desired result.

Comment: so i think you can provide that code dynamically into the modal is't it ?

Comment: If my answer works for you please mark it as correct. Thank you.

Comment: While a lot of the answers are very helpful. I was hoping to just modify my form posted alongside the question.

Comment: Hold tight and let me see what i can do.

Comment: in theory i did this all wrong and instead of you using target=_blank... just change that one line to... data-popup="true"

Comment: That should work.. and i updated my answer. @DataByDavid

Answer (score 2):

Upto my understanding you want to open a modal in angular2 onto which you want to perfrom some actions like login etc. here is code for you with working modal with validation in the angular2. using bootstrap modal.

## angular2 + popup + validations

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        {{demoInfo | json}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id='myForm' role="form" [ngFormModel]="CreateGroup">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.name' class="form-control" ngControl='name'>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-md-7">
            Password:   <input type="password" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.password' class="form-control" ngControl='password'>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" [disabled]='!CreateGroup.valid' (click)="addNewGroup(demoInfo)" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

working demo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/07X8LVnI01Ml2vkN0XwI?p=preview

hope it may help you !

Answer (score 1):

```
<form ngNoForm id="someid" action="//app.mailerlite.com/webforms/popup/123123" data-popup="true">
<div class="button-preview">
<button type="submit" class="ml-subscribe-button gradient-on">SIGN ME UP TODAY</button>
</div>
</form> 

// Wait for the document to become ready
$(function() {
    $("a[data-popup]").live('click', function(e) {
        window.open($(this)[0].href);
        // Prevent the link from actually being followed
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/

updated!

---

This should do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/b68Xb/

```
 <p>This is the main content. To display a lightbox click <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here</a></p>
        <div id="light" class="white_content">This is the lightbox content. <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>



.black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 16px solid orange;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: instead of this why not to use bootstrap-modal (popup)?

Comment: That would be a great idea as well but less code imo the better.

Comment: yes but why to use custom external css when there is facility provided by bootstrap.

Comment: I like your way of thinking, this was just the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Where do I add the JS code? in the index.html or in the component?

Comment: You may add it on the index. That will work fine. This is HTML5 @DataByDavid

Comment: I like your idea.... It is now navigating to the form url but I'll keep poking around.

Comment: its nice i have used this in angular 2 way 

 <!--popup-->
<div id="light" class="white_content" [hidden]="!showPopup">
<a style="float:right" href = "javascript:void(0)" (click)="showPopup=false" >Close</a>
  <tree-view [directories]="tree" [parentId]="deleteRole?._id"></tree-view></div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay" [hidden]="!showPopup"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Simple, easy, intuitive.

jQuery UI Dialog - http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```